# Adding progress bar to status bar causes other panels to go black

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, statusbar, toolstripstatuslabel

I have an application, where I have added a progress bar to the status bar. I started to notice, that when I launch the application and at the same time activate some other window, covering the area where my application will appear, and keep it in focus, so that when my application is up, it will be behind this window, all the status bar panes (toolstriplabels) will go black and refuse to refresh...
At the same time their background property stays "control".
If I remove the progress from the statusbar and repeat all the steps, panes will be normal.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: This rings a bell, but your question doesn't do much to revive the memory.  Try calling the status strip's Invalidate() method in an event handler for the form's Activated event.

Comment: I tried calling Invalidate() on each pane and then Refresh() for the dialog - no result.
Also I tried calling Activate() and Focus() from both constructor and Load handler - the same - no result... :(